# Bitcoin Transaction Unconfirmed

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core

I made a transaction on March 13th, transferring .88 BTC from my desktop wallet to another account. I have a Mac and am using Bitcoin-Qt version v0.8.1-beta. The transaction did not go through, my wallet is "out of sync", and I do not have the .88 BTC in my wallet anymore. I have scoured the internet trying to solve this problem and have not found anything yet. Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Let your wallet sync up. Then let us know what you see on the transaction page of the client. Is it there, but showing up as unconfirmed? Not there at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can see when is your transaction with : https://blockchain.info

If your wallet is out of sync don't worry, it's normal that you don't see the transaction.
If you sent BTC from A to B, B will see the transaction when he's synced.

Comment: My transaction does not show up on the blockchain, and it did not go through to btcsportsbet, the recepient. How do I recover my BTC?

Comment: You got something to search for the transaction in BlockChain ? ATM let A and B sync completely :) If you don't have enter the wrong address it's impossible that you lost your BTC.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. If others have this problem, the easiest solution is to find your wallet.dat file on your Mac, which is in in ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/

Import this folder into a new wallet on Blockchain.info. Your balance will show up in there and you will have access to your BTC.

That was fairly simple and I spent way to much time on that!

Comment: Can you clarify this process please? I transferred my bitcoins from one machine to another and it is unconfirmed. Does this mean I need to find my old machine to copy the wallet.dat file? I am using a restored version of my OS and data on a new machine from a Time Machine backup